What Polish(?) movie features a guy who cheats on wife and takes pictures
Some SPOILERS in the description of this movie.
I'm looking for the name of a foreign movie (maybe Polish) from around 2010 about a guy who cheats on his wife while he is away on business trips. Apparently, his wife also knows about the photos.
The guy is a taxi driver from what I remember. He takes his son-in-law with him to a pool table where they meet a woman with which they both have an affair. 
The woman then comes to work for the guy's daughter.
The guy's wife is also having an affair with a blind man who gives her a certain flower she keeps pressed in a book.
In the end, his wife dies and he burns his hand with an iron.
I can't recall any other details of the film, but if anyone can recognise it, I would appreciate it.

I managed to track it down:
Men in Hope (2011). It was actually made in the Czech Republic.
